# Reset Google Search layout

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome on a Mac and all of a sudden my Google search layout switched back to its old interface with a black bar on top.

I've tried logging out and logging in my account, cleared all navigation data, cache and cookies but to no avail.

It's clearly a Chrome issue since navigation with Safari is fine and I'm on a really fast connection.

Do you how I could get back to the new layout?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've decided to [reset Chrome back to its defaults](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3296214?hl=en), when you do that all extensions are automatically disabled. Everything appeared to be fixed but when I enabled them again I was back to the old layout.

Turns out I had an extension called Quick Javascript Switcher and I must've accidentally clicked the button to disable javascript for that page. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

- go to: **`chrome://settings/searchEngines`**
- and set: 


  ```
  {google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}
  ```
- or try:


  ```
  https://encrypted.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&safe=off&pws=0&hl=EN&q=%s
  ```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I ended up resetting Chrome https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3296214?hl=en